# PShape.setStroke throws ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Error

Tags: processing

The Processing handbook (second edition) has this as example 17-12:

```
PShape zig;

void setup() {
  size(100, 100);
  zig = createShape();
  zig.beginShape();
  zig.fill(0);
  zig.vertex(10, 0);
  zig.vertex(100, 30);
  zig.vertex(90, 70);
  zig.vertex(100, 70);
  zig.vertex(10, 90);
  zig.vertex(50, 40);
  zig.endShape(CLOSE);
  frameRate(4);
}

void draw() {
  background(204);
  color strokeVal = color(random(255));
  color fillVal = color(random(255));
  zig.setStroke(strokeVal);
  zig.setFill(fillVal);
  shape(zig, 0, 0);
}
```

Running this (in Processing 3.0a5) causes an error: "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16". The culprit is "zig.setStroke(strokeVal)".

Why does this error occur?

This is the code straight out of the book and even downloading & running the example code from the processing website results in the same error.

Comment: This looks like a known bug: https://github.com/processing/processing/issues/2784

Comment: Example 17-10 also didn't work due to a known bug. I don't understand why they'd be given as examples in the handbook if they don't work due to bugs!

Comment: @marcusround Because the examples were written for an older version of Processing. They worked when they were written. Then Processing went through a huge update, and a few things were broken in the process.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, but the thing is, it was a brand new revision of the book, the second edition was released in February 2015, only a few months before I asked the question. Surely the whole point of a revised edition is to update outdated code!